# Jquery or JavaScript image slider from JS array with thumbnails

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image-gallery

Please help, JavaScript and Jquery experts, 
How to make automatic image gallery slider with thumbnails, where target images' source paths are stored in Java Script array?

I have a JQuery image gallery automatic slider code with thumbnails, that works fine. But, as you can see target images are all placed in an unordered list in html. What I need is target images (i.e. img src) to be in JS array, so I need to modify my JS script, but I don't know how. So, I don't want images in html list, I just want a div with image which source is in JS array. I already have my JS array that I made from PHP array.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    var imgs = <?php echo json_encode($images); ?>;
</script>
```

Thanks in advance!!

```
    //IMAGE GALLERY

var triggers = $('ul.triggers li');
var images = $('ul.images li');
var lastElem = triggers.length-1;
var target;

triggers.first().addClass('active');
images.hide().first().show();


function sliderResponse(target) {
    images.fadeOut(800).eq(target).fadeIn(800);
    triggers.removeClass('active').eq(target).addClass('active');
}

triggers.click(function() {
    if ( !$(this).hasClass('active') ) {
        target = $(this).index();
        sliderResponse(target);
        resetTiming();
    }
});

$('.next').click(function() {
    target = $('ul.triggers li.active').index();
    target === lastElem ? target = 0 : target = target+1;
    sliderResponse(target);
    resetTiming();
});
$('.prev').click(function() {
    target = $('ul.triggers li.active').index();
    lastElem = triggers.length-1;
    target === 0 ? target = lastElem : target = target-1;
    sliderResponse(target);
    resetTiming();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with something like this, without change your script:

```
var imgs = <?php echo json_encode($images); ?>;

//create a list of img for each src in your array wrapped inside a li element
var _tmpl = "";
for(var k=0; k < imgs.length; k++){
    _tmpl+="<li><img src='"+imgs[k]+"' /></li>";
}

//then append the string inside wrapper the ul.images
var images = $(_tmpl);
var wrapper = $('ul.images');
images.appendTo(wrapper);

//then your script to create the slider
var triggers = $('ul.triggers li');
var lastElem = triggers.length-1;
var target;

triggers.first().addClass('active');
images.hide().first().show();


function sliderResponse(target) {
    images.fadeOut(800).eq(target).fadeIn(800);
    triggers.removeClass('active').eq(target).addClass('active');
}

triggers.click(function() {
    if ( !$(this).hasClass('active') ) {
        target = $(this).index();
        sliderResponse(target);
        resetTiming();
    }
});

$('.next').click(function() {
    target = $('ul.triggers li.active').index();
    target === lastElem ? target = 0 : target = target+1;
    sliderResponse(target);
    resetTiming();
});
$('.prev').click(function() {
    target = $('ul.triggers li.active').index();
    lastElem = triggers.length-1;
    target === 0 ? target = lastElem : target = target-1;
    sliderResponse(target);
    resetTiming();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to loop trougth the array to create the images elements.
Then append it to a `li`.
Then append all `li` to a `ul` with class `triggers`.
Then append this `ul` to your page.

The rest of your script stays the same.

```js
//var imgs = <?php echo json_encode($images); ?>;

var imgs = [
  "http://www.branfere.com/upload/Image/univers/univers08.jpg",
  "http://www.branfere.com/upload/Image/animaux/capucin01.jpg",
  "http://www.branfere.com/upload/Image/animaux/girafe01.jpg",
  "http://www.branfere.com/upload/Image/animaux/lemurien05.jpg",
];

var container = $("#ulContainer");

var list = $("<ul>").attr("class","triggers");

for(i=0;i<imgs.length;i++){
  var item = $("<li>");
  var img = $("<img>").attr("src",imgs[i]);
  item.append(img);
  list.append(item);
}

container.append(list);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="ulContainer"></div>
```

Comment: I need to thank you here, because I can't give upvote yet, because of my humble reputation score, I hope I could give you votes soon! Great solution!

Comment: It was a pleasure, no problem ;)